# How do I unlock additional trading carts for the Palico trader?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

Similar to the farm and Wycoon from previous games, Monster Hunter Generations has a "generate items for resource points" feature. In this game it takes the form of a Palico Trader where you can send off your Palicos to trade with other towns, and they come back with items. However, you only start off with one trading slot/cart.

How do you unlock additional Palico Trading Slots?

Comment: Since I haven't seen any and I'm in 5*, I assume they're from special quests in the Hunting Hub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All farm upgrades come from Prowler village quests.

- Jurassic Fungologist (2★) unlocks the mushroom trade.
- Bug Reports (3★) unlocks the insect trade.
- Marshlands Fishing? (4★) unlocks the fish trade.
- Kut-Ku Earbreaker (5★) unlocks the second cart.
- Surrounded by Blue and Green (6★) unlocks the third cart.

Source: [Kiranico](http://mhgen.kiranico.com/quest/village/). All of the farm upgrade quests are from Neko (Means "Cat").

Comment: I never did any prowler missions past village rank 1, and I have all 3 carts. Currently HR 132.

Answer (score 3):

You can additionally unlock everything by gaining HR from the hub. I don't have the exact numbers though on when things unlock. I believe I unlocked the second cart along with all the locations when I hit HR 4.

Answer (score 0):

When beating low rank, you unlock the second cart and all locations, so you don't need to do Prowler missions for those. Apparently gaining HR will unlock the third cart but the only way I know is to do the 6 star Prowler mission 'Surrounded by Blue and Green'