# Is there bulk fishing?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In MH4U there was an area you go could go to do some bulk fishing, that is, catch a lot of fish in a very short time with the help of your palicos.

Is there something like that in Generations? I tend to favor fish items (especially whetfish), and would like to begin stockpiling asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By completing the Marshland Fising quest in 4* you will unlock the Tanzia Fishing Market at the trader, which lets you trade for fish as you would for other types of resources.

Comment: 4* guild or village?

Comment: @Rapitor Generally, people use stars, such as 3*, to refer to village quests, and Hunter Rank, such as HR4 to refer to guild quests. In this case, yeah, it's 4* in the village(s).

Comment: @Rapitor See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275919/94356 for how to unlock the fish trading place. But there's no 4U's big fishing net equivalent in this game.